# Admin not loading - JS errors

Tags: magento2, admin, javascript

Suddenly my Magento 2.4.6 started to show a JS issue without any deployment. I had this issue below with the JavaScript loading.

[image: Magento 2.4.6 Admin Js issues]

How could I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an issues impacting the installations **2.4.4, 2.4.5, 2.4.6, 2.4.7** due to a JS conflict coming from http://assets.adobedtm.com/

A quick fix, for now, is to run these commands below and disable the admin tracking.

```
bin/magento config:set admin/usage/enabled 0;
bin/magento cache:clean;
```

Ref: [Admin Usage Tracking causes JS error #37618](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37618)